# Does MongoDB store documents in 4MB chunks?

Tags: mongodb

I read that MongoDB documents are limited to 4 MB in size.  I also read that when you insert a document, MongoDB puts some padding in so that if you add something to the document, the entire document doesn't have to be moved and reindexed.

So I was wondering, does it store documents in 4MB chunks on disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 1.8, individual documents are now limited to 16MB in size (was previously 4MB). This is an arbitary limitation imposed as when you read a document off disk, the whole document is read into RAM. So I think the intention is that this limitation is there to try and safeguard memory / make you think about your schema design.

Data is then stored across multiple data files on disk - I forget the initial file size, but every time the database grows, a new file is created to expand into, where each new file is created bigger than the previous file until a single file size of 2GB is reached. From this point on, if the database continues to grow, subsequent 2GB data files are created for documents to be inserted into.

"chunks" has a meaning in the sharding aspect of MongoDB. Whereby documents are stored in "chunks" of a configurable size and when balancing needs to be done, it's these chunks of data (n documents) that are moved around.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "no."  The actual space a document takes up in Mongo's files is variable, but it isn't the maximum document size.  The DB engine watches to see how much your documents tend to change after insertion and calculates the padding factor based on that.  So it changes all the time.

If you're curious, you can see the actual padding factor and storage space of your data using the `.stats()` function on a collection in the **mongo** shell.  Here's a real-world example (with some names changed to protect the innocent clients):

```
{14:42} ~/my_directory ➭ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.0
connecting to: test
> show collections
schedule_drilldown
schedule_report
system.indexes
> db.schedule_report.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test.schedule_report",
    "count" : 16749,
    "size" : 60743292,
    "avgObjSize" : 3626.681712341035,
    "storageSize" : 86614016,
    "numExtents" : 10,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 23101696,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.4599999999953628,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2899968,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 835584,
        "WeekEnd_-1_Salon_1" : 925696,
        "WeekEnd_-1_AreaCode_1" : 1138688
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So my test collection has about 16,749 records in it, with an average size of about 3.6 KB (*"avgObjSize"*) and a total data size of about 60 MB (*"size"*).  However, it turns out they *actually* take up about 86 MB on disk ("*storageSize*") because of the padding factor.  That padding factor has varied over time as the collection's documents have been updated, but if I inserted a new document *right now*, it'd allocate 1.46 times as much space as the document needs (*"paddingFactor"*) to avoid having to move things around if I change it later.  To me that's a fair size/speed tradeoff.